# Soft i2c with Sensirion SHT21 sensors on Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensor, i2c

I have tried checking with an oscilloscope on the analogue pins when the sensor is plugged in and I don't seem to get anything as I normally would.

The hardware i2c channel works just fine on the mega, its the soft ones I am trying to use that don't seem to work

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Ports.h>
#include <PortsSHT21.h>
#include <SHT2x.h>

//Define soft i2c channels for 3 sensors
  SHT21 hsensor2 (2); // pins A1 and D5 - Sensor 2
  SHT21 hsensor3 (3); // pins A2 and D6 - Sensor 3
  SHT21 hsensor4 (4); // pins A3 and D7 - Sensor 4

//define variables for temp data
  float h, t;


void setup() 
{
    Wire.begin();
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
   // Get data from first sensor hard I2C channel
    float hum1 = (SHT2x.GetHumidity());
    float temp1 = (SHT2x.GetTemperature());
    Serial.println("temp1");
    Serial.println(temp1); 

  // Get data from second sensor soft I2C
  hsensor2.measure(SHT21::HUMI);
  hsensor2.measure(SHT21::TEMP);
  hsensor2.calculate(h, t);
    float hum2 = (h);
    float temp2 = (t);
    Serial.println("temp2");
    Serial.println(temp2);     

   // Get data from third sensor soft I2C
  hsensor3.measure(SHT21::HUMI);
  hsensor3.measure(SHT21::TEMP);
  hsensor3.calculate(h, t);
    float hum3 = (h);
    float temp3 = (t);
    Serial.println("temp3");
    Serial.println(temp3);     

 // Get data from fourth sensor soft I2C  
  hsensor4.measure(SHT21::HUMI);
  hsensor4.measure(SHT21::TEMP);
  hsensor4.calculate(h, t);  
    float hum4 = (h);
    float temp4 = (t);
    Serial.println("temp4");
    Serial.println(temp4);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Same comment as for your answer from a few minutes ago: don't expect people to know what SHT21 is. Give more details if you want a proper answer. (Especially Olin is very sensitive to this :-), and rightly so)

Comment: I don't see any *relevant* code, like thouse for software I2C or for port setup: I2C ports need to be open-drain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness, I believe Jonny Flowers has found the solution himself: http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=99832.0

He's also put his code online: https://github.com/mrjonny2/PortsSHT21

His solution is to edit the Ports.h file's

```
uint8_t portNum;

inline uint8_t digiPin() const
    { return portNum ? portNum + 3 : 18; }
inline uint8_t digiPin2() const
    { return portNum ? portNum + 13 : 19; }
inline uint8_t anaPin() const
    { return portNum - 1; }
```

to

```
uint8_t portNum;

inline uint8_t digiPin() const
    { return portNum ? portNum + 3 : 18; }
inline uint8_t digiPin2() const
    { return portNum ? portNum + 53 : 19; }
inline uint8_t anaPin() const
    { return portNum + 53; }
```

Comment: Hi yes, I completely forgot about this, thanks for putting it in.  Did you find it on my paste bin?

Comment: Nah, I just googled and came across the arduino forum I linked in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I remember posting it somewhere.